# How to support different architectures on a podspec?

Tags: ios, static-libraries, cocoapods

In my company we are using some 3rd party static library that comes with a "wrapper" class and I want to create a pod for it. We have two versions of the static library, for simulator and device. The folder with the files that I want to include in the pod looks like this:

```
Engine
|
|- libEngine.a
|
|- libEngine-Simulator.a
|
|- Engine.h
|
|- EngineWrapper.h
|
|- EngineWrapper.mm
|
|- SomeOtherFile.bin
```

Now, since:

- The library only supports `armv7`
- `EngineWrapper.mm` is **not** using ARC
- there is a requirement to set `CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY` to `libstdc++` and
- `SomeOtherFile.bin` needs to be "seen" by `Engine.h`,

the related part of my podspec looks like that:

```
s.requires_arc = false
s.source_files = 'Classes/ios/Engine'
s.preserve_path = 'Classes/ios/Engine/SomeOtherFile.bin', 'Classes/ios/Engine/libEngine-Simulator.a', 'Classes/ios/Engine/libEngine.a'
s.vendored_libraries = 'Classes/ios/Engine/libEngine-Simulator.a', 'Classes/ios/Engine/libEngine.a'
s.xcconfig  =  { 'CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY' => 'libstdc++', 'VALID_ARCHS' => 'armv7' }
```

This is just one of the hundreds of combinations/different settings I tried. I can provide more examples if you want. However, no matter what I try, I get the following error when trying to build:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

I tried to go through all the settings in `Pods.xcodeproj` but I can't see something suspicious there (but at the same time I am not familiar with the way Cocoapods works in detail).

Among others, I tried to:

- keep a flat folder hierarchy (instead of the `Classes/ios/Engine` path)
- use [libraries](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#libraries) instead of `vendored_libraries`
- remove one of the static libraries
- create a fat binary instead of having the two ones
- zip all the files together (in the same way TestFlight does it in [their podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/TestFlightSDK/3.0.0/TestFlightSDK.podspec))
- remove the `VALID_ARCHS` setting

and I also saw several different podspec examples using static libraries, but without any luck..

I am using Cocoapods ver 0.32.1.

If you have any idea of what could be wrong, please let me know before I lose my sanity. Thanks!